# My answer is getting -1 as vote but it seems to be the solution

Tags: discussion

I have answered the following question: [Bluetooth-connection; can't send strings properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751797/bluetooth-connection-cant-send-strings-properly)
The author tested the code I proposed and said "it seemed to worked fine". I don't know why my answer get -1 vote instead of being selected as the question answer.

Comment: Don't sweat the occasional random downvote. They happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've seemed to answer the question by explaining what is wrong, and proposed a fix in a well structured and formatted answer using good English... so I can't see why either.

The only thing I can think of is either

1. Someone mis-clicked by accident
2. There is something wrong with the actual *code* you posted; although in these circumstances, it's common for people to comment and explain *what* exactly.

Whichever the case, I've given you a +1, so now you're on +8rep for the answer overall!

As an aside, if a user comments and asks for you to *explain code*, I would tend to update/ edit the answer and include the description in there, rather than adding it in comments as you did.

Comment: I also think about mis-click. Thanks for help and advice about editing answer.